# Unable to connect to Thingsboard running on localhost server using mosquitto/mqtt

Tags: arduino, localhost, mqtt, mosquitto, thingsboard

I am unable to connect to thingsboard running on localhost through MQTT. My arduino code worked well with Thingsboard's demo server. It connected succesfully and was able to see values under Latest Telemetry. While running locally, I am getting

```
"Connecting to ThingsBoard node ...[FAILED] [ rc = -2 : retrying in 5 seconds]"
```

error in arduino serial monitor.

I have installed tb-gateway and mosquitto broker. Following are the changes done:

tb-gateway.yml

```
    path: storage
    bufferSize: 1000
  connection:
    host: "127.0.0.1"
    port: 1882
    retryInterval: 3000
```

mqtt-config.json

```
{
  "host": "127.0.0.1",
  "port": 1883,
  "ssl": false,
  "retryInterval": 3000,
}
```

thingsboard.yml

```
 mqtt:
 # Enable/disable mqtt transport protocol.
 enabled: "${MQTT_ENABLED:true}"
 bind_address: "${MQTT_BIND_ADDRESS:0.0.0.0}"
 bind_port: "${MQTT_BIND_PORT:1882}"
 timeout: "${MQTT_TIMEOUT:10000}"
 netty:
```

Here is my arduino code :

```
#include <Wire.h>

#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

// MPU6050 Slave Device Address
const uint8_t MPU6050SlaveAddress = 0x68;

// Select SDA and SCL pins for I2C communication 
const uint8_t scl = 22;
const uint8_t sda = 21;

#define TOKEN "oPfC3R8p3LLKJ4lBU9u2" 

#define WIFI_AP ""     
#define WIFI_PASSWORD ""
char thingsboardServer[] = "127.0.0.1";
unsigned long lastSend;
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

WiFiClient wifiClient;
PubSubClient client(wifiClient);

// sensitivity scale factor respective to full scale setting provided in         
datasheet 
const uint16_t AccelScaleFactor = 16384;
const uint16_t GyroScaleFactor = 131;


int16_t AccelX, AccelY, AccelZ, Temperature;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  InitWiFi();
  client.setServer( thingsboardServer, 1883 );
  Wire.begin(sda, scl);
  MPU6050_Init();
  lastSend = 0;
}

void loop() {
  if ( !client.connected() ) {
    reconnect();
  }

   if ( millis() - lastSend > 1000 ) { // Update and send only after 1 seconds
    getAndSendData();
    lastSend = millis();
  }

  delay(10);
  client.loop();
}    

void getAndSendData(){
  double Ax, Ay, Az, T, Gx, Gy, Gz;
  Read_RawValue(MPU6050SlaveAddress, MPU6050_REGISTER_ACCEL_XOUT_H);

  //divide each with their sensitivity scale factor
  Ax = (double)AccelX/AccelScaleFactor;
  Ay = (double)AccelY/AccelScaleFactor;
  Az = (double)AccelZ/AccelScaleFactor;
  T = (double)Temperature/340+36.53; //temperature formula


  Serial.println("Collecting  Data ");

  Serial.print("Ax: "); Serial.print(Ax);
  Serial.print(" Ay: "); Serial.print(Ay);
  Serial.print(" Az: "); Serial.print(Az);
  Serial.print(" T: "); Serial.print(T);


  // Prepare a JSON payload string
  String payload = "{";
  payload += "\"Ax\":"; payload += String(Ax); payload += ",";
  payload += "\"Ay\":"; payload += String(Ay); payload += ",";
  payload += "\"Az\":"; payload += String(Az); payload += ",";
  payload += "\"temperature\":"; payload += String(T);
  payload += "}";

  // Send payload
  char attributes[100];
  payload.toCharArray( attributes, 100 );
  client.publish( "v1/devices/me/telemetry", attributes );
  Serial.println( attributes );
  Serial.println("%. Sent to Thingsboard.");

}

void I2C_Write(uint8_t deviceAddress, uint8_t regAddress, uint8_t data){
  Wire.beginTransmission(deviceAddress);
  Wire.write(regAddress);
  Wire.write(data);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

// read all 14 register
void Read_RawValue(uint8_t deviceAddress, uint8_t regAddress){
  Wire.beginTransmission(deviceAddress);
  Wire.write(regAddress);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(deviceAddress, (uint8_t)14);
  AccelX = (((int16_t)Wire.read()<<8) | Wire.read());
  AccelY = (((int16_t)Wire.read()<<8) | Wire.read());
  AccelZ = (((int16_t)Wire.read()<<8) | Wire.read());
  Temperature = (((int16_t)Wire.read()<<8) | Wire.read());

}

//configure MPU6050
void MPU6050_Init(){
  delay(150);
   .......
}

void InitWiFi()
{
  Serial.println("Connecting to AP ...");
      WiFi.begin(WIFI_AP, WIFI_PASSWORD);
 .......
}


 void reconnect() {
 // Loop until we're reconnected
 while (!client.connected()) {
 status = WiFi.status();
 if ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
   WiFi.begin(WIFI_AP, WIFI_PASSWORD);
   while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
     delay(500);
     Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to AP");
}
Serial.print("Connecting to ThingsBoard node ...");
// Attempt to connect (clientId, username, password)
if ( client.connect("fa5c6fe0-05cc-11e9-bfc6-27e4379bb947", TOKEN, 
  NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) ) {
  Serial.println( "[DONE]" );
} else {
  Serial.print( "[FAILED] [ rc = " );
  Serial.print( client.state() );
  Serial.println( " : retrying in 5 seconds]" );
  // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
  delay( 5000 );
  }
 }
}
```

Please let me know in case I am missing any configuration or doing something wrong.

Comment: You seem to have a miss match in port numbers (1882/1883) check that they are consistent, MQTT normally runs on 1883

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ESP8266 code has set the IP address `thingsboardServer` to 127.0.0.1 - that will never work for the ESP8266.

127.0.0.1 is a special IP address - it's `localhost` - it always refers to "self". Used on the computer running ThingsBoard, it will refer to that computer, but used on another computer it refers to the other computer. No other computer or device will be able to connect to the ThingsBoard server using 127.0.0.1.

It's like if you say "I like cake" and then your friend says "I like pie". 127.0.0.1 is "I" - your friend saying "I like pie" doesn't mean you like pie.

You need to find out the correct IP address of the server you're trying to connect to. If you're running it on a Linux computer you can use `/sbin/ifconfig` to list your network interfaces. Ignore `lo` - that's `loopback`, which is `localhost` and 127.0.0.1. If the server has a wired (ethernet) connection, look for `en0` or `enp0s##` or something like that, with an `inet addr`. If it's connected to wifi, look for something like `wlan0` or `wlp5s0`. The names vary depending on the OS and the hardware, so you'll have to figure that out for yourself.

For instance, on one of my Linux computers:

```
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:85:c2:00:12:76
          inet addr:10.0.1.104  Bcast:10.0.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7886:c2fe:fd00:1872/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:846697237 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:96279263 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:167800766971 (167.8 GB)  TX bytes:34595177085 (34.5 GB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fb400000-fb420000
```

That computer's IP address is 10.0.1.104.

This will work on a Macintosh as well.

If you're running on Windows, [this article](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=27309) will help you find your IP address. Do not use a web service like https://www.whatismyip.com/ - that will tell you the IP address of your router, not the IP address of your computer.

Once you have the correct IP address, use it in your ESP8266 code instead of 127.0.0.1.

In your `tb-gateway.yml` and `mqtt-config.json` files, you're telling the server to only listen on 127.0.0.1. You should double check the documentation, but you almost certainly need to change this to 0.0.0.0 in both files. That should tell the server to listen on all network devices. Without that change it won't be able to communicate with anything that's not running on the same computer.

Once you do that, be aware that anything on your network will be able to talk to your MQTT server; you should configure it with proper access controls if that's a problem for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply. Much appreciated. It helped a lot. By changing IP address it worked. :)